# Bluetooth is not connecting

Tags: bluetooth

I have an UB500 bt adapter starting last week it's not connecting to all my devices, it keeps auto disconnecting. I have tried many things, updating the Ubuntu OS,  reinstall Bluetooth drivers.

Comment: Question has no details that could be used to understand the issue and offer any help. Where is the Ubuntu version info? What commands have you tried? What errors have you received? What are the other BT devices the question implies? Pleas edit the question and add some details.

Answer (score 0):

This may not help a lot but when I tried to connect fake air pods via Bluetooth they kept reconnecting and disconnecting and then finally connected stably after 5-10 min. Maybe, just maybe your devices are not authentic otherwise you should replace the adapter using a warranty or something. BUT before you do any of this make sure the drivers are properly installed.